# How to send crashlogs from device to registered email without syncing to itunes or without any contact to xcode

Tags: ios, crash-reports

If any crash happens while using iOS application, crash logs are created in the device. Now I want my application crashlogs to be sent to my email address in .txt file when ever crash happens in my application with all details.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to look up link below:

https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics

Maybe it could help you .

Comment: Thank You but I dont want to use any frameworks/ coocapods.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *stackArray = [exception callStackSymbols];
NSString *reason = [exception reason];
NSString *name = [exception name];

// Get exception infomation.
NSString *exceptionInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Exception reason：%@\nException name：%@\nException stack：%@",name, reason, stackArray];
```

// send message to server, if you don't want to tell user you send a email to your server. maybe you need to read https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage get more detail message.

Comment: Thanks. How to use this and where to use this. how the above code will know the crash happened.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can define a C method.
// first
void uncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *exception) {
NSArray *stackArray = [exception callStackSymbols];
NSString *reason = [exception reason];
NSString *name = [exception name];

// Get exception infomation.
NSString *exceptionInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Exception reason：
%@\nException name：%@\nException stack：%@",name, reason, stackArray];

/**
 send email
**/
}

//second set this method like this in appdelegate.m 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //regist method 
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This works only for uncaught exceptions not for crashes which happens with in my code.